# Initializing tinyMCE after triggerSave (previously saved data persists)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I have a strange problem. I have tinyMCE editor in an mvc view used for adding items. I call tinyMCE.triggerSave to persist the data for data submission. Problem is, the next time I open the respective view, the content of the tinyMCE editor is already set to the previous content.

I tried to clear the contents using setContent(), but it doesn't always work, because I call this on document.ready using javascript and the editor isn't always fully loaded at that time.

Any ideas? This is really a headache.

PS: If I no longer call triggerSave(), I don't get any data from the editor on submit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, using delayed execution :

```
   var t = setTimeout(function () {
    if (typeof textEditorForCreate != null)
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
}, 400);
```

Maybe not the most elegant of solutions, but it works for me.